# Read text of multiple round rectangle buttons

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am creating a UIView which will contain more than 26 round rectangle button. I am using a NSString called Title. I want to set Title=[text of Selected Round rectangle button].

I can't use switch method here as that should be used if a there are more than 26 posisble values of a single round rectangle button. I can do it by  creating more than 26 methods (one for each round rectangle button) but I don't want to do that. There should be a way to do it by using only few lines of code. I want to use only a single method which will do following

variableText= [text of Selected Round rectangle button].
Title = VariableText

How do I know which round rectangle was selected? How do I get the [text of Selected Round rectangle button] value without creating 26 different method?

Answer (score 0):

Route the touch events for all buttons to the same `IBAction`:

```
-(IBAction) pressedButton:(UIButton*)button
{
  self.title = button.titleLabel.text;
  //...
}
```